# Conditional joint density based on the sum

Tags: statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be independent random variables that have a (positive) joint density $f_{XYZ}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$, with positive marginals $f_X$, $f_Y$, $f_Z$.

How do we obtain the density $(X,Y,Z)$ conditional on $X+Y+Z$?

The joint density of  $(X,Y)$ conditional on $X+Y+Z$ seems to be doable based on the strategy in this question:
[Conditional density of Sum of two independent and continuous random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473790/conditional-density-of-sum-of-two-independent-and-continuous-random-variables)
but in this question, the change of variables and the explicit calculation of the Jacobian seems to be important, and I don't know how to apply this here.

Example using e.g. Gaussian random variable would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Take $E_k=\{x+y+z=k\}\cap \mathbb{R}^3$. The conditional pdf of $(X,Y,Z)$ given that $(X,Y,Z)\in E_k$ is $$f_{XYZ|E_k}(x,y,z)=\frac{f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\cdot 1_{E_k}(x,y,z)}{\iint_{E_k}f_{XYZ}\mathrm{d}S}$$ In fact, if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ is arbitrary, then $$\mathbb{P}\left((X,Y,Z)\in A|(X,Y,Z)\in E_k \right)=\frac{\iint_{E_k\cap A}f_{XYZ}\mathrm{d}S}{\iint_{E_k}f_{XYZ}\mathrm{d}S}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you saying that $\mathbb{P}(E_k)=\iint_{E_k}f_{XYZ}\mathrm{d}S$? But $X+Y+Z$ is (e.g. for $X$, $Y$, $Z$ being independent Gaussian) just a Gaussian random variable. Why don't you have $\mathbb{P}(E_k)=\mathbb{P}({X+Y+Z=k})=0$?

Comment: This does *not* say $\mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z=k)$ equals $\iint_{E_k}f_{XYZ}\mathrm{d}S$. You should try to show using this formula that if $X,Y,Z\sim \exp(\lambda)$ are iid, and if $k>0$, then the $$(X,Y,Z)|E_k\sim \mathcal{U}(E_k)$$

Comment: My question is more of how to derive this formula; cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473790/conditional-density-of-sum-of-two-independent-and-continuous-random-variables. I get that you should have the surface measure on $E_k$ as $E_k$ is a lower dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and thus Lebesgue measure zero there, but I don't see how you derive that.